# jQuery: Changing order of divs with prependTo

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify all div-boxes with the class `.tabs` and change some div-order inside.

I'd like to push the `.team-member-name` inside the `.team-member-description` for every div-element with the class `.tabs`

**Beginning**:

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="team-member-name">Mirko</div>
  <div class="team-member-description"> <p>Text</p></div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="team-member-name">Marko</div>
  <div class="team-member-description"> <p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

**Result**:

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="team-member-description">
     <div class="team-member-name">Mirko</div>
     <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="team-member-description">
    <div class="team-member-name">Marko</div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried it with the following, but every .team-member-name is now placed in .team-member-description :(

```js
$(".tabs > .team-member-name").each(function(){
    $(this).prependTo($(".team-member-description"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` and find target by `.siblings()`

```js
$(".tabs > .team-member-name").each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).siblings(".team-member-description"));
});
```

```css
.team-member-description {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="team-member-name">Mirko</div>
  <div class="team-member-description">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="team-member-name">Marko</div>
  <div class="team-member-description">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, that helps. Thank you for your fast answer :)